# How to load one javascript file on all forms without adding it manually in crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

How can I load javascript file on each page instead of adding it manually each item in Form Library. For example I want to always load jquery and a helper js file on any form.

Answer (score 4):

**Supported**

The best you can do is have a button configured to show on the application ribbon or for all entities that includes the library as an action.

That way it will probably be loaded whenever you need it. It is only really of any use if you have a button you can attach it to though.

**Unsupported**

Inject the JS library into your pages using IIS

Answer (score -2):

Maybey you can update edit.aspx once and include your script there.