# Call a javascript function on each and every entity crm 2011 without adding it on entity form

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

What am trying to do here is :-While creating a record from any entity, i query logs entity if a record is found for current entity...on save of current entity record, fetch this logs record and pop it. But i don't want to add the JavaScript resource on each and every entity form.

I want some way of calling my function on each and every entity without adding it to the form. Doesn't matter whether it is unsupported or supported.

Comment: Please see my previous answer to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207725/how-to-load-one-javascript-file-on-all-forms-without-adding-it-manually-in-crm-2/19208076#19208076

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this seems like a really bad idea. Why fight CRM's process for doing this? Why is it so hard to add the javascript library to each form manually? Why would you be willing to make an unsupported change to your environment for such little gain?

However, I can think of a supported way to do this (I think). You could write a plugin on the Publish message that would go add that javascript web resource to the form if it isn't already there. This way, every time you publish entities, the plugin would be responsible for adding that javascript to the form in a supported manner.

But I really don't think this is worth you or your client's time. If it is, I want to work for your client! :)

Comment: thanks josh..could u give me some example code to add a javascript code on the form.. :)